# Benign values for small and big date

Tags: ruby

I have to write a function that returns date. In some cases it returns "zero" date, in some cases it returns "infinity" date. By zero and infinity I mean values that are respectively smaller and bigger than any correct dates. What values should I return?

I was considering creating class with `<=>` method defined:

```
class ZeroDate
  def <=>(val)
    -1
  end

  include Comparable
end
```

This approach can be enriched by checking if compared object is of `Date` kind, so it could not be used in wrong context.

It works pretty well as long as my object is receiver, but there is no way to ensure that users of this object will place it on left side of comparison.

What other solutions would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

<del>Since the `<=>` operator simply does `<`, `=`, then `>` you could define those three to return `true`, `false`, `false` respectively and you should have pretty much all cases covered.</del>

**EDIT**:

You're right, that is the same and doesn't answer the question you asked. I'll try to make up for it:

If you make `ZeroDate` inherit from `Date`, they will be both comparable

```
require 'date'

class ZeroDate < Date
  def <=>(val)
    -1
  end
end
```

and the comparison will be interchangeable

```
z = ZeroDate.new()
b = Date.new(2001,2,3)

b < z #=> false
b == z #=> false
b > z #=> true

z < b #=> true
z == b #=> false
z > b #=> false
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as providing `<=>` and including `Comparable`. It is not working if my object is not a receiver in comparison call.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is coincidence it works properly. `Date.new` returns special date '-4712-01-01' which is lesser than '2001-02-03' :) This way there is no way to create the other object I was looking for (infinity date).

Comment: That's true. I'm afraid the only valid solution here would be to change the `Date` class comparison itself to account for `ZeroDate` to be always smaller. Infinity is harder to achieve here than I previously anticipated.